# Data Virtulization Or Deffered Loading in List View of Windows App

Tags: win-universal-app

I have a `ListView` inside `ScrollViewer` like so:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="svSubmisssions"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                            Margin="0 10 0 0"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            RelativePanel.Below="cbConsultant">
                    <ListView x:Name="lvSubmisssions"
                            Margin="0 10 0 0"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dtSubmissions}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding SubmissionList}"
                            SelectionMode="Multiple"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"                                                      
                          MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=page,Path=ActualWidth}"                             
                          /></ScrollViewer>
```

My Item source `SubmissionList` has a very huge amount of data available.
I would like to implement lazy loading in `ListView` , so only some of data is loaded onto the page. I have implemented pagination to get the data, so initially it is getting only 10 records. I want when user scroll down the page, the next 10 record from the database will appear. i.e Page no 2. so record 11 to 20, so the page will now have total 20 records.

Comment: By the way, why did you place your `ListView` inside `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: @AndriiKrupka  Yes , I have tried it.

Comment: No, virtualization is already done with `ListView` control, please refer to [Using virtualization with a list or grid (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx), and there is also a `ScrollViewer` inside `ListView`, so what you are doing is in kind of wrong way. I met this problem once, and from your code,  Is that possible that you have also a `StackPanel` outside of your `ScrollViewer`?

Answer (score 0):

You should to use `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface

Read about it on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh701916)

Look at [the sample](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/implementing-the-isupportincrementalloading-interface-in-a-window-store-app/)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it loads every pages in first go, One after another. It is not loading when user scroll down.

Comment: If in your case `It is not loading when user scroll down`, you did somethig wrong